# How do I index the entire C: drive in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, search-indexing

I figured out how to index my whole C: drive in Windows 10. It was easy. The new Windows Explorer is incredibly helpful.

One of my co-workers, who is still stuck on Windows 7, just asked me why her search was no longer turning up folders and files that it had been days ago... I have no idea what she messed up to unindex everything, but I believe that just indexing the C drive again should fix her issue, right? She wants to be able to type into the start menu and have files and folders come up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### How do I index the entire C: drive in Windows 7?

- "Start" > "Control Panel" > "Indexing Options"
- Click "Modify"
- Check "Local Disk C:"

  [image]
- Click "OK"
- Click "Close"

Comment: Thank you! This helps a million. I appreciate the detail and screenshots.

Answer (score 0):

Click the Windows Start button and type “index”. When the field populate select “Indexing Options”. Click the Modify button and select the locations you want to index.